# Unable to connect to kafka cluster from outside

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I have created my kubernetes cluster from https://github.com/LinkedInLearning/kafka-on-kubernetes-2899691.git but iam unable to consume or produce message externally although iam able to do so inside the cluster anyone can please help me out to connect to kafka cluster externally

I have tried creating a Load balancer but iam unable to consume or produce with that also